# Pandas read_csv adding a leading 0

Tags: python, csv, pandas

**Edit -** because of the issues I have encountered I decided the best thing to do is check if the length of the column is 10 digits long and the first character is a 0, strip the 0. Anyone have an efficient way to do that? Here is what I am thinking so far. Second edit - I think this is working. I still don't understand why there are leading 0s in the file on some dates when I read it as an object though if someone could educate me.

aht['ivr_session'] = aht['ivr_session_id'].astype(str).apply(lambda x: np.where(((len(x) == 10) & (x[0] == '0')), x.lstrip('0'), x))

**Original Problem:**
There is a column in my raw data which is 9 digits long but if I read the csv with dtype = {session_id : object}, there is suddenly a leading 0.

Here is a value_count of the character length:

```
10    240392
9      10316
Name: session_id, dtype: int64
```

The weird thing is that if I remove the dtype parameter (which means that pandas infers the data as a float):

```
9     211451
10     39248
Name: ivr_session_id, dtype: int64
```

If I open the .csv file in Excel and count the character length, it is 9. What is causing this leading 0 to be generated in pandas? The actual column is 9 characters long. I am trying to merge this 9 digit session_id with another file with the same key. If pandas thinks that there are 10 characters then it will not join properly.

Something even more crazy is that the data on January 11th and 12th of this month is still showing 10 characters even if I don't read the file as an object. The csv shows 9 characters though. I honestly do not know why two days would be incorrect when everything looks the same.

This gets rid of the decimal when the float is converted to a string. The raw data also has padded 0s at the end of the datetime columns so I need to remove those as well (is there a way for parse dates to take care of this?)

```
aht['session_id'] = aht['session_id'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.split('.')[0])
aht['call_start'] = aht['call_start'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.split(':000')[0])
aht['call_end'] = aht['call_end'].astype(str).map(lambda x: x.split(':000')[0])
```

Comment: FYI - I checked all of the raw data and the actual session_ids never start with a 0 so perhaps someone can help me create a rule to only grab 9 characters and strip off a leading 0, if it exists?

Comment: Please provide a link to the csv you're having problem with. Several lines with problematic data will suffice.

Comment: I checked the data in notepad++ instead of Excel and there really is a leading 0 sometimes. I guess Excel truncates that 0 when you view the file which caused some confusion on my end. I think I need to be more careful about this and not rely on Excel csv files... for now I am checking if the data has 10 characters and starts with '0', lstrip the 0.

Comment: @LanceDacey believe you need to adjust the cell type in excel to see what's 'actually' in the .csv file. when the cell type is general, excel is going to guess at the type of the data. in most cases date fields are strings and not ints but excel doesn't know that. for example, see how excel treats a field that looks like 01182016.

Comment: @n8sty yes if I import the field as text rather than open the file as csv then there is a leading 0.  Quite annoying how excel can be a bit deceptive. Is there a better spreadsheet to view output? I still use excel to double check stuff..

Comment: @LanceDacey you probably don't want to use excel unless some end-user is going to be consuming your output from python (and whatever) else with excel. to check the work it's probably better to print the head of your csv files to the terminal/command line or just inspect using pandas or some other tool.